# How to add when a checkbox is checked and deduct when unchecked in Javascript when html id is a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, checkboxlist

I am trying to total a particular column amounts from a php array when a checkbox is checked and deduct from the total when it is unchecked. I can get it to add when checked but can not get it to reduce from the total when unchecked. In fact the code below adds every time the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Please help

```
    <html>
<body>
<?php
 $testArray = [100000,200000,300000,144444,154444,16444,174444,18444];  
?>
<div>
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($testArray);$i++) { ?>
<input type="checkbox"  id = <?php echo $i ?> onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $testArray[$i] ?>)" value="<?php echo $testArray[$i] ?>" ><?php echo $testArray[$i] ?> <br/>

<?php } ?>
</div>
<table>
<tr style = "display: none;" >
    <td></td>
    <td id = 'balance'> 0 </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Total  :  </td>
    <td id = 'balance1'> 0 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
// cumulative = 2
function myFunction(x){
balance = document.getElementById('balance').textContent;
total   = parseInt(balance)
total = total + x
document.getElementById('balance').textContent = total
// display with number formated
total = total.toLocaleString("en-US");
document.getElementById('balance1').textContent = total
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($testArray);$i++) { ?>
    <script>
        if (document.getElementById("<?php echo $i ?>").checked === true) total += x;
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```